# MGS error in fresh install

Tags: magento2.3.3

I just installed Magento 2.3.3 with a theme which includes MGS Frontend Builder.

If I try to open Catalog - categories or products
Try to login as a customer or just try to change the configuration to flat products and categories Im getting this error:

> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Swatches\Data::getProductMediaGallery(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
>   $product) must be compatible with
>   Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data::getProductMediaGallery(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
>   $product): array in

Does anybody know how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to theme so contact to support or more solution check this [link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/MGS-Frontend-Builder-Issue/m-p/103850#M6270)